# How to calculate ISO Week "iW" in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for how I would calculate the ISO/iW in PostgreSQL 9.6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT), it should be

```
EXTRACT (week FROM atimestamp)
```